# Qt 5.8.0 MSVC2015_64bit Error

Tags: qt

This is my first time in Qt 5.8.0, when I build my project it shows following errors.

Error while building/deploying project test_qt (kit: Desktop Qt 5.8.0 MSVC2015_64bit)
When executing step "qmake"

When I go to options I saw some wrong configurations.
[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSCf2.png) the picture.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not clear enough

Comment: If you hover the error icon, you can get more details about the errors.